# MySQL: Single qoute issue in passing parameter to a storedprocedure

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am sending a comma separated list to my stored procedure from PHP. Stored procedure is like below:

```
UPDATE RolesMenus SET Enabled=1 WHERE MenuID IN(prmMenusList) AND RoleID = prmRoleID;
```

Now problem is that when I pass a list of menus(prmMenusList) through code it just updates the value of just first element in the list. This is, I think, due to some single quote around the list. Query may be formed like:

```
UPDATE RolesMenus SET Enabled=0 WHERE MenuID IN('1,7,19,20,21,26') AND RoleID = 74;
```

How can I avoid the situation?

Here I have added the CodeIgniter(PHP) code:

```
Public function enableMenus($selectedMenus, $roleID){
                    $menusList = "";
                    foreach($selectedMenus as $item){
                        $menusList .= $item.",";
                    }
                    $menusList = substr($menusList, 0,strlen($menusList)-1); // to remove the leading comma
                    $result=$this->db->query("call uspEnableMenus('".$menusList."',".$roleID.")");
                    $tempResult = $result;
                    $result->next_result();
                    return $tempResult->result();
                }
```

Comment: Please post also PHP code also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. :)

Just used the query as follow:

```
UPDATE RolesMenus SET Enabled=1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(MenuID,prmMenusList) AND RoleID = prmRoleID;
```

OR:

```
UPDATE RolesMenus SET Enabled=1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(MenuID,'1,2,3,4') AND RoleID = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

send the `prmMenusList` as a list of integers instead of a string:

```
UPDATE RolesMenus SET Enabled=0 WHERE MenuID IN(1,7,19,20,21,26) AND RoleID = 74;
```

In case that your stored procedure does only that update, I think you could write your whole function like:

```
Public function enableMenus($selectedMenus, $roleID){
                    $this->db->where_in('MenuID', $selectedMenus);
                    $this->db->where('RoleID', $roleID);
                    $result = $this->db->update('RolesMenus', array( 'Enabled' => 0 ) ); 
                    $tempResult = $result;
                    $result->next_result();
                    return $tempResult->result();
                }
```

As far as I've seen until now, there is no straight forward method to pass an array to a stored procedure. 
You could create another stored procedure that parses your string containing the ids, creates a temp table that stores your array values, then send that temp table as a parameter to your actual stored procedure. 
But, in my opinion that is much more of a headache:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `YourDB`.`sp_parseIntList` $$ 
CREATE DEFINER=`hotstuff`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_parseIntList`( 
_intlist TEXT ) 
BEGIN 

DECLARE comma INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE mylist TEXT DEFAULT _intlist; 
DECLARE temp TEXT DEFAULT ''; 
DECLARE strlen int DEFAULT LENGTH(_intlist); 


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable (num int) TYPE=INNODB; 


SET comma = LOCATE(',',mylist); 

WHILE strlen > 0 DO 
IF 
comma = 0 
THEN 
SET temp = TRIM(mylist); 
SET mylist = ''; 
SET strlen = 0; 
ELSE 
SET temp = TRIM(SUBSTRING(mylist,1,comma)); 
SET mylist = TRIM(SUBSTRING(mylist FROM comma+1)); 
SET strlen = LENGTH(mylist); 
END IF; 

IF CAST(temp as UNSIGNED) != 0 
THEN 
INSERT INTO TempTable VALUES(CAST(temp as UNSIGNED)); 
END IF; 
SET comma = LOCATE(',',mylist); 
END WHILE; 

SELECT * FROM TempTable; 

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable; 



END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Tudor, How the list of integers can be passed to a stored procedure and how to process them? also I have edited my post with php code

Comment: Tausif, does this edit of the post help you solve your problem?

Comment: Actually, regarding first approach, I am bound to just pass parameters some how and rest of the functionality to perform with stored procedures. And about Second, It's not a recommended way to go through :(